# Querying custom product_type Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'v created a custom `product_type` in Woocommerce as below.

```
 function register_simple_booking_product_type() {
        class WC_Product_Booking extends WC_Product{ 
            public function __construct( $product ) {
                $this->product_type = 'booking';
                parent::__construct( $product );

            }

        }


    }
    add_action( 'init', 'register_simple_booking_product_type' );

    function add_simple_booking_product( $types ){

        $types[ 'booking' ] = __( 'Simple booking' );

        return $types;

    }
    add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_simple_booking_product' );
    function simple_booking_custom_js() {

        if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
            return;
        endif;

        ?><script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
                jQuery( '.options_group.pricing' ).addClass( 'show_if_booking' ).show();
            });
        </script><?php
    }
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'simple_booking_custom_js' );
```

From here I would like to query the product by `product_type`. Though the product_type appears in the `post_meta` in the Wordpress database, the products created as `booking` type only appear when I query for `simple` product type. How can I query for just products of the `booking` `product_type` ?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'booking',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Have you tried querying by the `term_id` instead of the slug, just to rule that out?

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I understand your question wrong, but if the "product_type" is a meta data, you should not use 'tax_query'. Check out meta query for a solution

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query